# angular this.formGroup.get('elemName').value returns a weird json object

Tags: angular, formgroups

I have the following code in my project (the problem shows up in the tipoDoc variable):

```
this.formGroup = this.fb.group({
      valutazioneNuovoDoc: [false],
      tipoDoc : new FormControl(2),
      note: ['']
    });

this.fileTypeOptions = this.fileTypeOptions || [
  { label: "Carta di identita", value: "CI" },
  { label: "Dichiarazione dei redditi", value: "DR" },
  { label: "Certificazione unica", value: "CU" },
  { label: "Foto tessera", value: "FT" }
]
```

Then in my .html component

```
<div>
      <div class="peav-upload-file-type col-6 form-group">    
      <p-dropdown [options]="fileTypeOptions" formControlName="tipoDoc" optionLabel="label" optionValue="value"></p-dropdown>
    </div>
```

My problem: whenever i try to access the selected value of this p-dropdown, as follows:

```
console.log('tipoDoc.value: ' + JSON.stringify(this.formGroup.get('tipoDoc').value) );
```

i get this json object, instead of a fileTypeOptions value:

```
tipoDoc.value: {"validator":null,"asyncValidator":null,"pristine":true,"touched":false,"_onDisabledChange":[],"_onChange":[],"_pendingValue":2,"value":2,"status":"VALID","errors":null,"valueChanges":{"_isScalar":false,"observers":[],"closed":false,"isStopped":false,"hasError":false,"thrownError":null,"__isAsync":false},"statusChanges":{"_isScalar":false,"observers":[],"closed":false,"isStopped":false,"hasError":false,"thrownError":null,"__isAsync":false}}
```

The weird thing is that this happens only the first time, after selecting any item from the menu. If after the first choice i change my selection it then starts to work correctly.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

the issue here is that your'e initializing tipodoc with formControl as default value, then when you select a value from list it's being overridden and hence the issue is gone.
try to init the formGroup this way -

```
this.formGroup = this.fb.group({
      valutazioneNuovoDoc: [false],
      tipoDoc : [2],
      note: ['']
    });
```

Comment: I tried to change my code as you suggested, but unfortunately it didnt' work, the behaviour is still the same

Comment: can u add an angular app snippet with your usecase on stackblitz or something so I'll be able to help u further